# Can't get HTTP basic auth with Google Kubernetes Engien Nginx ingress controller

Tags: docker, authentication, nginx, kubernetes

According to the Kubernetes docs, the Nginx Ingress Controller supports adding basic authentication. The required Ingress annotations that I'm setting are:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: namespace/secret
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: "Authentication Required"
```

My ingress controller image is: gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.11

I cannot find any logs from the ingress controller that would indicate errors, but basic auth is not present. In case it matters, I am using cert-manager to provision Let's Encrypt TLS certificates, which is working nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong controller/annotations. These annotations are for https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx which has this official [image](https://quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.17.1)

You have examples of how to deploy the controller [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml)

If you want to use gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.11, the annotations are:

```
ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: "Authentication Required"
```

Comment: Note: the OP has the right annotations for current versions of nginx ingress, but for the ancient 0.9 version they're using, this answer is correct.

Answer (score -2):

You can find full articles [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/auth) or [here](https://docs.giantswarm.io/guides/advanced-ingress-configuration/#authentication).

To configure basic authentication on Nginx Ingress there are two things that should be in place:
(I assume you already have ingress controller running on your cluster)

1. A Secret with  a name and content of username/passwords in base64 encoded line should exist:
   (In this example, the name “basic-auth” is used  as a name of the Secret but you can choose any valid name you want.) Username: `foo`, password: `bar`

   ```
    $ htpasswd -c auth foo
    New password: bar
    Re-type new password: bar
    Adding password for user foo

    $ kubectl create secret generic basic-auth --from-file=auth
    secret "basic-auth" created

    $ kubectl get secret basic-auth -o yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    data:
      auth: Zm9vOiRhcHIxJE9GRzNYeWJwJGNrTDBGSERBa29YWUlsSDkuY3lzVDAK
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
      name: basic-auth
      namespace: default
    type: Opaque
   ```
2. An Ingress object should exist in the same namespace with the Secret:
   (here we use a default namespace for Ingress and Secret )

   ```
    echo "
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: ingress-with-auth
      annotations:
        # type of authentication
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
        # name of the secret that contains the user/password definitions
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
        # message to display with an appropriate context why the authentication is required
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: \"Authentication Required - foo\"
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: foo.bar.com
        http:
          paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: <your_backend_service_name>
              servicePort: <your_backend_service_port>
    " | kubectl create -f -
   ```

To verify your configuration check replies using GET request with or without authentication:
(`30xxx` - get port number from output of the command `kubectl get svc --all-namespaces | grep ingress-nginx | grep NodePort`)

```
$ curl -v http://cluster.node.ip.address:30xxx/ -H 'Host: foo.bar.com'
...
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
...

$ curl -v http://cluster.node.ip.address:30xxx/ -H 'Host: foo.bar.com' -u 'foo:bar'
...
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

On the next step, you can add SSL or TLS configuration of your choice to Ingress object specification.

**Update**: The above example still works fine on the [current nginx ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#bare-metal) v0.44.0

I recon *cert-manager* configuration shouldn't affect the way ingress controller manages plain HTTP traffic if SSL/HTTPS isn't enforced.

`htpasswd` could be installed as a part of Ubuntu/Debian package `apache2-utils` or `httpd-tools` for CentOS:

```
apt install apache2-utils
yum install httpd-tools
```

For *ngninxinc* version of the ingress-controller consider reading the [issue #200](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/200)